# How to run python script from another .py file and show in current window

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

## menu.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.lang import Builder


class CustDrop(DropDown):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CustDrop, self).__init__( **kwargs)
        self.select('')


kv_str = Builder.load_string('''


BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
            Color:
                rgb: (1,1,1)
        size_hint_y:1

        Button:
            id: btn
            text: 'user'
            on_release: dropdown.open(self)
            #size_hint_y: None
            #height: '48dp'  


        CustDrop:

            id: dropdown

            Button:
                text: 'List User'
                size_hint_y: None
                height: '48dp'

        Label:
            size_hint_x: 4

    Label:
        size_hint_y: 9

''')


class ExampleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv_str

if __name__ =='__main__':
    ExampleApp().run()
```

## user.py

```
import kivy

kivy.require('1.9.0')  # replace with your current kivy version !
import sqlite3 as lite
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty, ListProperty, StringProperty, ObjectProperty,NumericProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.recyclegridlayout import RecycleGridLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.core.window import Window



Window.size = (500, 500)

#con = lite.connect('user.db')
#con.text_factory = str
#cur = con.cursor()


class SelectableRecycleGridLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior,
                                  RecycleGridLayout):
    ''' Adds selection and focus behaviour to the view. '''


class SelectableButton(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Button):
    ''' Add selection support to the Button '''
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
        self.index = index
        return super(SelectableButton, self).refresh_view_attrs(rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        ''' Add selection on touch down '''
        if super(SelectableButton, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)

    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        ''' Respond to the selection of items in the view. '''
        self.selected = is_selected


    def on_press(self,*args):
        popup = TextInputPopup(self)
        popup.open()

    def update_changes(self):
        self.text = txt


class RV(BoxLayout):
    data_items = ListProperty([])

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.get_users()

    def get_users(self):

        # cur.execute("SELECT * FROM `users` order by id asc")
        # rows = cur.fetchall()

        rows = [(1, 'Yash', 'Chopra'),(2, 'amit', 'Kumar')]

        for row in rows:
            for col in row:
                self.data_items.append(col)


class ListUser(App):
    title = "Users"

    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('user.kv')
        return RV()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    ListUser().run()
```

## user.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<SelectableButton>:
    # Draw a background to indicate selection
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (.0, 0.9, .1, .3) if self.selected else (0, 0, 0, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<RV>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        GridLayout:
            size_hint: 1, None
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 25
            cols: 3

            Label:
                text: "ID"
            Label:
                text: "First Name"
            Label:
                text: "Last Name"

        BoxLayout:
            RecycleView:
                viewclass: 'SelectableButton'
                data: [{'text': str(x)} for x in root.data_items]
                SelectableRecycleGridLayout:
                    cols: 3
                    default_size: None, dp(26)
                    default_size_hint: 1, None
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.minimum_height
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    multiselect: True
                    touch_multiselect: True
```

I have two file menu.py and user.py. menu.py file show menu and user.py shows list of user..
when i run menu.py then shows user menu on top .When i click on user then 'list user' show(submenu of user).When i click on 'list user' then user list should show  in current window.Menu will be on top and user-list show in same window(under menu).

Comment: The solution is similar to the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47111074/kivy-python-how-to-run-a-python-file-from-another-python-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To dsiplay the user list in the same window, combine both Python scripts and kv files into one. Please refer to the example below for details.

## Example

### mainmenu.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown

from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty, ListProperty, StringProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.recyclegridlayout import RecycleGridLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
import sqlite3 as lite

dbPath = "/home/iam/dev/SQLite/sampleDB/ChinookDB/"
#con = lite.connect('user.db')
con = lite.connect(dbPath + "chinook.db")
#con.text_factory = str
cur = con.cursor()


class MessageBox(Popup):
    obj = ObjectProperty(None)
    obj_text = StringProperty("")

    def __init__(self, obj, **kwargs):
        super(MessageBox, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.obj = obj
        self.obj_text = obj.text


class SelectableRecycleGridLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior,
                                  RecycleGridLayout):
    ''' Adds selection and focus behaviour to the view. '''


class SelectableButton(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Button):
    ''' Add selection support to the Button '''
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
        self.index = index
        return super(SelectableButton, self).refresh_view_attrs(rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        ''' Add selection on touch down '''
        if super(SelectableButton, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)

    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        ''' Respond to the selection of items in the view. '''
        self.selected = is_selected

    def on_press(self):
        popup = MessageBox(self)
        popup.open()

    def update_changes(self, txt):
        self.text = txt


class RV(BoxLayout):
    data_items = ListProperty([])

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.get_users()

    def get_users(self):
        cur.execute("SELECT CustomerId, FirstName, LastName FROM 'customers' order by CustomerId asc")
        rows = cur.fetchall()

        for row in rows:
            for col in row:
                self.data_items.append(col)


class CustDrop(DropDown):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CustDrop, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.select('')


class MainMenu(BoxLayout):
    users = ObjectProperty(None)
    dropdown = ObjectProperty(None)

    def display_users(self):
        # rv = RV()
        self.dropdown.dismiss()
        self.users.add_widget(RV())


class MainMenuApp(App):
    title = "Example"

    def build(self):
        return MainMenu()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainMenuApp().run()
```

### mainmenu.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<MessageBox>:
    title: "Popup"
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 400, 400
    auto_dismiss: False

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        TextInput:
            id: txtinput
            text: root.obj_text
        Button:
            size_hint: 1, 0.2
            text: "Save Changes"
            on_release:
                root.obj.update_changes(txtinput.text)
                root.dismiss()
        Button:
            size_hint: 1, 0.2
            text: "Cancel Changes"
            on_release: root.dismiss()

<SelectableButton>:
    # Draw a background to indicate selection
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (.0, 0.9, .1, .3) if self.selected else (0, 0, 0, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<RV>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        GridLayout:
            size_hint: 1, None
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 25
            cols: 3

            Label:
                text: "ID"
            Label:
                text: "First Name"
            Label:
                text: "Last Name"

        BoxLayout:
            RecycleView:
                viewclass: 'SelectableButton'
                data: [{'text': str(x)} for x in root.data_items]
                SelectableRecycleGridLayout:
                    cols: 3
                    default_size: None, dp(26)
                    default_size_hint: 1, None
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.minimum_height
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    multiselect: True
                    touch_multiselect: True

<MainMenu>:
    users: users
    dropdown: dropdown

    orientation: 'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
            Color:
                rgb: (1,1,1)
        size_hint_y:1

        Button:
            id: btn
            text: 'user'
            on_release: dropdown.open(self)

        CustDrop:
            id: dropdown

            Button:
                text: 'List User'
                size_hint_y: None
                height: '48dp'
                on_release: root.display_users()

        Label:
            size_hint_x: 4
            text: "label 1"

    BoxLayout:
        id: users
        size_hint_y: 9
```

### Output

[image]